# Is typo-squatter "StackExchage.com" (no "n") violating Jeff & Joel's intellectual property?

Tags: discussion, domain-names, trademark, intellectual-property

The typo-squatter running "stackexchage.com" (note: no "n") puts the name "StackExchange" (WITH the "n") in a couple prominent places on their website. Are they violating Jeff and Joel's copyright/trademark/other intellectual property?

Here's a screenshot so that you don't have to visit their URL, artifically increasing its perceived value:

[image: stackexchage.com]

Comment: or http://stackxchange.com?

Comment: I bet they didn't even pay for that stock art.

Comment: Of course, that cheesy stuff is available on *all* the free sites.  Good point reminding everyone *not* to visit the site and encourage this crap.  +1 for that.

Comment: From their "about us" page: "We've taken the confusion out of searching online, allowing you to find what you want in a timely manner"... riiight.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is just a placeholder. The image-links are leading down to this: http://www.smartname.com/smartname/

Answer (score 5):

Their use of the "Stack Exchange" trademark is blatant [trademark infringement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_infringement) since they're using an identical mark for Internet services. SE could initiate [UDRP proceedings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Domain-Name_Dispute-Resolution_Policy) against whoever owns the parked domain.

Comment: Yeah that top left logo is certainly trademark infringement (assuming SE has the relevant trademarks...you guys do, right?)

Comment: @BenBrocka: I don't think SE even needs a registered trademark for UDRP purposes, only if they actually intend to sue.

Comment: I find it interesting that the UDRP rules suggest that the act has to have been done in "bad faith."  Trademark holders deserve protection regardless of the squatter's motivations.

Comment: @RobertHarvey probably to reinforce protections like Parody; an identifiable parody does no harm as no one should be confused; typosquatting to drive advertising revenue is abusing confused users for profit